# Change value of JSON string with ruby

Tags: ruby

I hate to have to request this but could you help me to understand how to use Ruby. Considering this JSON production_data below what should I write to change the value of my size?

item.production_data
 => {"size"=>"001", "barcode"=>"4236002000", "dev_size"=>"U"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not JSON data; it's a Ruby hash.  You can create a JSON *string representation* of the hash by requiring 'json' and calling `to_json` on it:

```
require 'json'
h =  {"size"=>"001", "barcode"=>"4236002000", "dev_size"=>"U"}
puts h.to_json
```

If you want to change a value, just change it in the Ruby hash:

```
h['size'] = '999'
```

Then, if you need JSON, call to_json on the hash again:

```
puts h.to_json
```